# "The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192"

Tags: apt

I am new to ubuntu and I just installed it. when I tried to install git using "apt-get install git" I received error with "unable to connect". Then I found this question and did as what the question said. I installed git without any problem(I also installed vim and postgresql, no problem). But I received the following the error when I do "apt-get update".

```
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

Then I replaced the sources.list with the original one--the previous one when I had problem using apt-get install. and the strange thing is that I can use apt-get install(all i did was just stop using the list file and used another one and then revert to the original one and the original one suddenly works for install) I still have the same error with update.

so what was wrong previously? why did I receive error now?

Comment: I just got this error message myself. I have reason to believe that in my case the error message is caused by a previous download having been corrupted. I don't know how to identify the corrupted file and force a new download of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

i.e. paste using SHIFT + INS the number you have copied - **16126D3A3E5C1192**

You'll have to enter your password, the key will be downloaded and integrated.

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: I have been using Ubuntu for years, and I have **never** had to manually install signing keys in order to run `apt-get update`. Also the error message is **not** indicating that the public key is missing but rather that the signature is bad.