# Why does lubuntu 14.04 synaptic no longer reload?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

Effective the turn of this year the Synaptic Package Manager for Lubuntu 14.04 on ALL my computers STOPPED WORKING!!! (I have 5 computers, all with matching Lubuntu OS's.)

I still get updates of a sort--that's all.

I cannot reload without errors like the following:

```
   Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I get similar readings on ALL my computers.

I really do NOT want to have to find a new OS that will work on ALL my comps--it took me too long to find Lubuntu. PLEASE HELP!!!!!!

I tried to post it, but this forum considers my reply to be "links" and will not let me post it--I used the Ubuntu Repository Generator (very carefully, I'm no novice).

Afterwards I had far less errors, but still errors--the errors I have left were in the ORIGINAL install!!!

I have scoured the Net for the past 3 weeks trying to find an answer--NOTHING!!!

OK, I have copied what you sent into the repo list (deleting everything that was there FIRST)--(I know what I am doing here--just not how to solve my problem)

After I did that I ran `sudo apt-get update` --this was what came up;

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Failed to fetch http:  //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

REMEMBER I copied exactly what you sent and put it in the file all by itself and this is what I got......

UPDATE: I partially solved the problem, but still have the problem....

I went to Repositories in Synaptic and un-checked "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" then un-checked "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" then also, "Software restricted by copyright or legal issues"

THEN, I ran update again--this is what I got left:

```
Failed to fetch http:  //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There is NOT MUCH left to UN-CHECK!!!!!

Now your beginning to see my problem--where do I look to find this "binary" thing and get RID OF IT?!

NEW UPDATE-- I copied my repository list...

```
deb http:  //  us .archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

deb http:  //  us .archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main


deb http:  //  security .ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main

deb http:  //  archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://  archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

When I try to update I get the following:

```
Failed to fetch http:  //  us.archive .ubuntu .com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

QUESTION--I need to know WHERE to look for this erroneous data so I can DELETE IT!!!

NEW INFORMATION: On the advice I found elsewhere I ran the following--I don't know what this means, but I think you might....

```
x@x-Inspiron-8600:~$ ping -c 3 www.ubunu.com
PING www.ubunu.com (69.172.201.208) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.ubunu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms

x@x-Inspiron-8600:~$
```

Comment: Try this, it seems to have the same problems and a solution ["The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399985/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig-16126d3a3e5c1192). The probles seems to be that it does not want to run the equivalent of `sudo apt-get update` as it cannot verify the found files.

Comment: Fixed that and now this-- Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Could you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/596911/edit) into your question the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: So how do I find where these wrongful data are stored to delete them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Comment: I tried to edit your question so that the error output is clearly readable as error output but I'm noticing that a lot of your post references `ubunu.com` which is not `ubuntu.com` -- not sure what's going on there. I also see a lot of tabs in your `sources.list` -- not sure how those are getting introduced?

Answer (score 0):

"malformed file" is a syntax error. You need to check your /etc/apt/sources.list file and check the error message again as it should specify the exact line where the error occurred in that file.

use:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to edit the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file. Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit the file and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

here's a default list of sources to compare to:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: BTW, this list has all the backports and multiverse restricted universe etc enabled but those are not needed (optional).