# Failed to fetch APT update (Not a duplicate)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, update-manager

I've already checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399985/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig-16126d3a3e5c1192) answers, none of them works in my case. Here is what I'm getting when I run `sudo apt-get update` on my `14.04` LTS laptop:

```
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [336 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [350 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,832 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [176 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]                   
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages [14 B]           
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages [5,866 kB]   
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages [5,866 kB]    
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]        ^[[B^[[B
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB]  
Fetched 7,516 kB in 22min 42s (5,514 B/s)                                      
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've already tried `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists` before doing an update again, but it didn't work. Here are the repos which are enabled in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
```

**EDIT**

As I explained in the comments, the answer to the linked question didn't work out for me. I've already tried removing the `lists` folder and running `apt-get clean`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Thanks, but removing the `lists` folder and `apt-get clean` didn't work for me. Already tried that.

Comment: Did you try to change the mirror?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch - Yup. Tried the following three mirrors: `archive.ubuntu.com`, `in.archive.ubuntu.com` and `us.archive.ubuntu.com`. Same result with each.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Thanks! I switched to the German mirror and it worked. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I generated a clean and minimal `sources.list` from [repogen](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) having only `main` and `universe` sections. Then, I made a thorough reset of my `apt` system by following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

But even that didn't solve the problem. Then I located the problem source to the `universe` section of the repo line in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
#deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
```

I found that after commenting the `universe` section, `apt-get update` worked without any problems, but with `universe` added, I was getting this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Then as per the suggestion of @FlorianDiesch, I tried switching the servers: I tried the main, Indian and American ones, but with no luck:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
```

Finally, the I tried the German server and it paid off!

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
```

Now, `apt-get update` did a proper update without any issues. This seems to suggest that either the `Release` files of the other servers have some issues in them or they just don't like my machine setup for some reason.