# How to : Fix the problem to upgrade system on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

I was updating my system on Ubuntu 14.04 and show some message error like this

```
W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry '-/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)   
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

how can I fix this problem in my system?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue recently, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/728462/49938) is how it was resolved.

In short, try these things in a sequence:

1. Just do a `sudo apt-get update` and see if it resolves.
2. (optional) If you have meddled with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` a lot, then generate a new clean one from [repogen](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php).
3. Perform a `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/` followed by `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`.
4. No luck? Then problem is most likely with the ubuntu servers, not your configuration. Try switching the servers. Edit the `sources.list` and change `id.archive.ubuntu.com` (or whatever your present server is) with any of these:

   - `de.archive.ubuntu.com` (Germany)
   - `in.archive.ubuntu.com` (India)
   - `us.archive.ubuntu.com` (USA)
5. After you change the above, perform a `sudo apt-get update`. If not successful, go back to step-4 and pick another server and then repeat the process. Keep switching servers until you find the correct one. There are of course, many other servers too besides these three.

Answer (score 0):

Look for entries under these places. Open Terminal windows(Ctrl+Alt+T) and then type

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

grep 'sudo' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

On side notes also check
that you haven't checked "Software restricted by Copyright or Legal issues" under Software Sources. 
If it it is checked then uncheck and then try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it should work.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry '-/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: and then E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.